# The Quantum Operations On The Bipartite Systems

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, fa.functional-analysis

Given two distinct and noninteracting quantum mechanical
systems $\mathfrak{S}\_1$ and $\mathfrak{S}\_2$ with state spaces
$\mathcal H\_1$ and $\mathcal H\_2$, respectively, the state space
of the combined system $\mathcal S\_1+\mathcal S\_2$ is the
tensor product Hilbert space
$\mathcal H=\mathcal H\_1\otimes\mathcal H\_2$. Density operators
$W\in\mathcal D(\mathcal H)$, and effects
$F\in\mathcal E(\mathcal H)$. Similarly, there are corresponding
symbols $W\_i\in\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_i),
F\_i\in\mathcal E(\mathcal H\_i)$ for subsystems
$\mathfrak{S}\_i(i=1,2)$, respectively.

Given any quantum operation, $\Phi:
\mathcal D(\mathcal H)\rightarrow \mathcal D(\mathcal H)$, of
the composite system $\mathcal S\_1+\mathcal S\_2$.

**Problem:** (1) Do there exist whether or not two quantum
operation $\phi\_1$ and $\phi\_2$, of the subsystems $\mathfrak{S}\_1$
and $\mathfrak{S}\_2$, respectively, such that the following
diagram is commutative:

$$
\begin{diagram}
\node{\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_1)} \arrow[4]{e,t}{\phi\_1}\node[4]{\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_1)}\\
\node{}\\
\node{\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_1\otimes\mathcal H\_2)}
\arrow[2]{n,l}{Tr\_2} \arrow[4]{e,t}{\Phi} \arrow[2]{s,l}{Tr\_1}
      \node[4]{\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_1\otimes\mathcal H\_2)} \arrow[2]{s,r}{Tr\_1} \arrow[2]{n,r}{Tr\_2}
\\
\node{}\\
\node{\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_2)} \arrow[4]{e,b}{\phi\_2}
   \node[4]{\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_2)}
\end{diagram}
$$
i.e.
$$\begin{eqnarray}
Tr\_2(\Phi(W))&=&\frac{tr(\Phi(W))}{tr(\phi\_1(Tr\_2(W)))}\phi\_1(Tr\_2(W)),\\
Tr\_1(\Phi(W))&=&\frac{tr(\Phi(W))}{tr(\phi\_2(Tr\_1(W)))}\phi\_2(Tr\_1(W)),
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $\phi\_i: \mathcal D(\mathcal H\_i)\rightarrow
\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_i)(i=1,2)$ and $Tr\_i:
\mathcal D(\mathcal H)\rightarrow
\mathcal D(\mathcal H\_i)$ is a *partial trace* with respect to the subsystem $\mathfrak{S}\_i(i=1,2)$.

(2) If quantum operation  $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ exist, give the
relationship among the quantum operations $\Phi, \phi_{1}$ and
$\phi_2$.

Comment: I have edited the slab of LaTeX which you seemed to have pasted in **without using the preview function**. Please have a look at the guidelines as to what MO does and doesn't support, and how to get round them.

Comment: @Yemon: Your (heroic!) edit doesn't seem too successful to me. I am getting this text: Unknown environment "diagram".

Comment: @Harald: if you saw what happened before my edit, I think the present version is a considerable improvement:) I had insufficient zeal/charity for trying to work out what the diagram was supposed to depict and then recoding it

Comment: @Yemon: Yes, I had looked at the edit history. That's why I said “heroic”. Not complaining, really.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question right, essentially what is being asked is: for a general quantum operation on a system with two subsystems, can you learn what happens to subsystem 1 just by looking at the initial state of subsystem 1, and what happens to subsystem 2 just by looking at the initial state of subsystem 2. If this is what is being asked, the answer is No: consider the case where the two subsystems have the same dimension and the quantum operation $\Phi$ which swaps the subsystems.